# Force text with <sup> Tag to same height in table as another cell without <sup> Tag

Tags: html, css

I have a table with 2 cells, in one cell I have a , that cell will be moved downwards (see fiddle). How can I force both cells to be aligned?
Same goes with , then the whole text-cell is moved upwards. That looks strange, I would imagine to have all text in the same height, independent of sup and sub Tags.

https://jsfiddle.net/9Lsfxzte/

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Some sub text <sub>sub</sub></td>
    <td>Some Text</td>
    <td>Some Text with sup <sup>123</sup></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider empty pseudo element where you define the behavior of `sup` and `sub` to make sure it behave the same:

```css
td::before {
 content:"";
 vertical-align:sub;
}
td::after {
 content:"";
 vertical-align:super;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Some Text</td>
  <td>Some Text with sup <sup>123</sup></td>
  <td>Some Text with sub <sub>123</sub></td>
</tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr>
  <td>Some Text</td>
  <td>Some Text with sup <sup>123</sup></td>
</tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr>
  <td>Some Text</td>
  <td>Some Text with sub <sub>123</sub></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't understand what this is doing

Comment: @ZohirSalak it make sure all the td will have at least a sub and a sup element thus the alignment of the main text will always look the same.

Comment: @TemaniAfif what is your opinion on Terry's solution? This looks very neat

Comment: Can't we simply `vertical-align:top;` ?

Comment: @rst another solution among many ;) the difference with my solution is that the height will not increasse by adding sup while in my solution I am increasing the height with pseudo element to have the space for the sub/sup ready. each one can be useful in different situations. add background-color to notice the difference

Comment: @ZohirSalak no, it won't work. Remove the pseudo element and try. It will only work with sub and vertical-align:bottom will work with sup

Comment: Yes, That's the idea, Making the alignment relative to the line instead.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the browser's native styling for `sup` is:

```
sup {
    vertical-align: super;
    font-size: smaller;
}
```

...which in turn influences the height of the cell. You can simply use other means of vertical aligment without affecting the cell height, such as positioning the `<sup>` element relatively:

```css
sup {
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  top: -.35em;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Some Text</td>
  <td>Some Text with sup <sup>123</sup></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

use bootstrap then u can see smooth UI

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class="table">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td>hi</td>
    <td>hi</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tr style="height:auto">
  <td>Some Text</td>
  <td>Some Text with sup 
  <sup>123</sup></td>
</tr>
</table>
```